# How can I add query string in my symfony2 URL?

Tags: symfony, routes

I want to get URL like this--

```
http://www.mehedi.com/name/random/?key=mehedi&count=5&page=1
```

For this purpose I wrote my route like this-

```
name_random_list:
    path:     /name/random/
    defaults: { _controller: NameListBundle:Name:random}
    methods: [GET]
```

This URL work ok with my current route but I wanted to get same URL but with symfony default route validation. Describe more below by code-

```
name_random_list:
        path:     /name/random/{key}/{count}/{page}
        defaults: { _controller: NameListBundle:Name:random}
        methods: [GET]
        requirements:
          count: \d+
          page: \d+
```

this populated like this --

```
 http://www.mehedi.com/name/random/mehedi/10/1  // in here key=mehedi, count=10,page=1
```

but I want like this--

```
http://www.mehedi.com/name/random/?key=mehedi&count=5&page=1
```

with default validation of symfony.

Answer (score 0):

> with default validation of symfony.

Nope, I think it's not possible. You will have to write your own validation... which is farely  easy using [Filters](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php)

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this? I can't test this right now, but it's worth a try.

```
name_random_list:
    path:     /name/random/{questionmark}key={key}
    requirements:
         questionmark = [?]
```

Otherwise, I think your better of to handle this kind of things in your controller. Or write your own implementation of the ControllerResolverInterface (see [this link](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolverInterface.html)). But I don't think this is a very good idea to do, unless you know what your doing :P

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

`name_random_list:
    path:     /name/random{queryString}
    defaults: { _controller: NameListBundle:Name:random}
    methods: [GET]
    requirements:
       queryString: \?.+`

You can now generate something like:

http://blablabla.tld/name/random?whatever=wow&wow=blablabla